# Where could I find an implementation of SVM on Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, svm

I found an implementation in http://code.google.com/p/cascadesvm/. 
However, there are no specifications about that. Has anyone tried that? Or where could I find an alternative implementation of SVM on Hadoop?
Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone did this within the Mahout project, not sure if it's been merged into trunk, but this looks like a good place to start:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-232

Comment: Nope, didn't get it into the trunk or is not working properly. (Closed/LATER not Resolved).

Comment: Thanks. However, Mahout-232 / Mahout-334 didn't parallelize a binary SVM classiﬁer. It just use the strategy that each Mapper or Reducer has one independent SVM binary classiﬁer to get a corse parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it out https://code.google.com/p/cascadesvm/
The training part, and a demo in Matlab version are released.
https://code.google.com/p/cascadesvm/wiki/CascadeSVMMatlabVersion